How can I contact support?
I'm new here and haven't found a way to contact support.
Since I can't participate in the chat yet this is my only option.
So please could you tell me how I can contact the support here?
A moderator deleted my comment because it was too similar to the previous answer even though I only clarified something and I wasn't able to reply/comment on other user's answers.
I'd like to contact support to resolve this issue.

If you want to dispute the deletion of your answer, then you should post on the Anime & Manga Meta site and make the case for why you believe the answer should not have been deleted. The moderators there will either accept your argument and restore the answer, or explain why they believe the deletion was correct and explain how you could improve the answer.
You can also contact the community team by selecting "Contact" in the site footer. In your case, you can select "Stack Exchange Q&A Issue" -> "My question or answer did not meet quality standards", and then provide an explanation of why you think the answer should not have been deleted. It can take a while for the community team to respond, so posting on Meta should definitely be your first course of action.
